# Printing based on a 2D array of booleans

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a little bit of trouble trying to print data from a two dimensional array of booleans. The point of this exercise is to create a maze game where the boolean values true and false indicating if a space is blocked or not respectively with the S indicating the start and G the goal. I don't understand why, but when the maze prints, it seems to think every value of the array is true, even though I've previously set the values of the array read from a text file.

This is the code for the whole class:

```
package solution;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

/**
 * A maze game.
 * 
 * @author
 * @version August 29th 2019
 *
 */
public class MazeGame
{
    /**
     * The size of each side of the game map.
     */
private final static int HEIGHT = 19;
private final static int WIDTH = 39;

/**
 * The game map, as a 2D array of ints.
 */
private boolean[][] blocked;

/**
 * The current location of the player vertically.
 */
// TODO: add field here.
private int userRow;
/**
 * The current location of the player horizontally.
 */
// TODO: add field here.
private int userCol;
/**
 * The scanner from which each move is read.
 */
// TODO: add field here.
private Scanner moveScanner;
/**
 * The row and column of the goal.
 */
// TODO: add fields here.
private int goalRow;
private int goalCol;
/**
 * The row and column of the start.
 */
// TODO: add fields here.
private int startRow;
private int startCol;
/**
 * Constructor initializes the maze with the data in 'mazeFile'.
 * @param mazeFile the input file for the maze
 */
public MazeGame(String mazeFile)
{
    // TODO
    loadMaze(mazeFile);
    moveScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
}

/**
 * Constructor initializes the maze with the 'mazeFile' and the move 
 * scanner with 'moveScanner'.
 * @param mazeFile the input file for the maze
 * @param moveScanner the scanner object from which to read user moves
 */
public MazeGame(String mazeFile, Scanner moveScanner)
{
    // TODO
    loadMaze(mazeFile);
    this.moveScanner = moveScanner;
}

/**
 * getMaze returns a copy of the current maze for testing purposes.
 * 
 * @return the grid
 */
public boolean[][] getMaze()
{
    if (blocked == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    boolean[][] copy = new boolean[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = blocked[i][j];
        }
    }
    return copy;
}

/**
 * setMaze sets the current map for testing purposes.
 * 
 * @param maze
 *            another maze.
 */
public void setMaze(boolean[][] maze)
{
    this.blocked = maze;
}

/**
 * getUserRow returns the value in the userRow field.
 * 
 * @return the row the user is in
 */
public int getUserRow()
{
    return userRow;
}

/**
 * setUserRow sets the row the user is currently in.
 * 
 * @param userRow the row value
 */
public void setUserRow(int userRow)
{
    this.userRow = userRow;
}

/**
 * getUserCol returns the value in the userCol field.
 * 
 * @return the column the user is in
 */
public int getUserCol()
{
    return userCol;
}

/**
 * setUserCol sets the column the user is currently in.
 * 
 * @param userCol the column value
 */
public void setUserCol(int userCol)
{
    this.userCol = userCol;
}

/**
 * getStartCol returns the value in the startCol field.
 * 
 * @return the column the start is at
 */
public int getStartCol()
{
    return startCol;
}

/**
 * setStartCol sets the column the start is in.
 * 
 * @param startCol the column value
 */
public void setStartCol(int startCol)
{
    this.startCol = startCol;
}

/**
 * getStartRow returns the value in the startRow field.
 * 
 * @return the row the start is in
 */
public int getStartRow()
{
    return startRow;
}

/**
 * setStartRow sets the row the start is in.
 * 
 * @param startRow the row value
 */
public void setStartRow(int startRow)
{
    this.startRow = startRow;
}

/**
 * getGoalCol returns the value in the goalCol field.
 * 
 * @return the column the goal is at
 */
public int getGoalCol()
{
    return goalCol;
}

/**
 * setgoalCol sets the column the goal is in.
 * 
 * @param goalCol the column value
 */
public void setGoalCol(int goalCol)
{
    this.goalCol = goalCol;
}

/**
 * getGoalRow returns the value in the goalRow field.
 * 
 * @return the row the goal is in
 */
public int getGoalRow()
{
    return goalRow;
}

/**
 * setGoalRow sets the row the goal is in.
 * 
 * @param goalRow the row value
 */
public void setGoalRow(int goalRow)
{
    this.goalRow = goalRow;
}

/**
 * getMoveScanner returns the scanner moveScanner.
 * 
 * @return the scanner moveScanner
 */    

public Scanner getMoveScanner()
{
    return moveScanner;
}

/**
 * setMoveScanner sets the Scanner moveScanner.
 * 
 * @param moveScanner the Scanner
 */
public void setMoveScanner(Scanner moveScanner)
{
    this.moveScanner = moveScanner;
}

/**
 * Function loads the data from the maze file and creates the 'blocked' 
 * 2D array.
 *  
 * @param mazeFile the input maze file.
 */
// TODO: private void loadMaze(String mazeFile)
private void loadMaze(String mazeFile)
{
    blocked = new boolean[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    try 
    {
        File file = new File(mazeFile);
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);           
        int c = 0;
        while (fileScanner.hasNext()) 
        {
            String character = fileScanner.next();
            switch (character) 
            {
                case "S":
                    startRow = c / WIDTH;
                    startCol = c % WIDTH;
                    blocked[c / WIDTH][c % WIDTH] = false;
                    break;
                case "G":
                    goalRow = c / WIDTH;
                    goalCol = c % WIDTH;
                    blocked[c / WIDTH][c % WIDTH] = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    blocked[c / WIDTH][c % WIDTH] = 
                        Boolean.valueOf(character);
            }
            c++;
        }
        fileScanner.close();                                
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
/**
 * Actually plays the game.
 */
public void playGame()
{
    
}

/**
 * Checks to see if the player has won the game.
 * @return true if the player has won.
 */
// TODO: public boolean playerAtGoal()
public boolean playerAtGoal()
{
    return false;
}
/**
 * Makes a move based on the String.
 * 
 * @param move
 *            the direction to make a move in.
 * @return whether the move was valid.
 */
public boolean makeMove(String move)
{
    // TODO
    return false;
}

/**
 * Prints the map of the maze.
 */
public void printMaze()
{
    // TODO
    System.out.println("*---------------------------------------*");
    for (int i = 0; i < blocked.length; i++)
    {   
        System.out.print("|");
        for (int j = 0; j < blocked[i].length; j++)
        {
            if (i == startRow && j == startCol)
            {
                System.out.print("S");
            }
            else if (i == goalRow && j == goalCol)
            {
                System.out.print("G");
            }
            else if (blocked[i][j] = true)
            {
                System.out.print("X");                   
            }
            else if (blocked[i][j] = false)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }               
        }
        System.out.println("|");            
    }
    System.out.println("*---------------------------------------*");
}

/**
 * Creates a new game, using a command line argument file name, if one is
 * provided.
 * 
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String mapFile = "data/easy.txt";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    MazeGame game = new MazeGame(mapFile, scan);
    game.playGame();
}
}
```

The first line of the maze should be something like:

`|SX          X     X         X          |`

But instead it prints:

`|SXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|`

I don't understand why it thinks every value in the array is true, help would be very appreciated.

Comment: it thinks every value is true since you are assigning true to every value - `blocked[i][j] = true` - just because it is part of an `if` does not change its meaning

Answer (score 3):

Because you are not comparing, you are assigning. Use double equals. I mean:

instead of

```
else if (blocked[i][j] = true)
```

and

```
else if (blocked[i][j] = false)
```

try

```
else if (blocked[i][j] == true)
```

and

```
else if (blocked[i][j] == false)
```

---

Or better still:

```
else if (blocked[i][j])
```

and

```
else if (!blocked[i][j])
```

Comment: I mean, use double equals, not arrows. Sorry for using wrong term.

Comment: And welcome to community if you are new :))

Comment: don't use `==`, use the simpler, safer and *cleaner* `if (foo)` or `if (!foo)`. In this case it would be: `else if (blocked[i][j]) {...}` or `else if (!blocked[i][j]) {...}`

Comment: Thank you for help @Andreas :)) I didn't see it at first look and I thought that editing will be available after a while :D

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ++

Comment: Wow, thank you guys so much for the quick help! I went to edit my post to include more code for a few minutes and I already have an answer when I come back, that's awesome!